# Exception Handling in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Am creating a powershell script for Biztalk deployment. I wrote a normal try catch block to handle the exceptions during the deployment. My Code was able to catch the Exceptions like

# File Not Found
 # Syntax Errors

But exception like `Dependency applications needs to be installed before installing` - was not getting caught. But when i check the Powershell console i can see..
`CommandExecuted with 1 Error`.

Please Suggest how to handle these exceptions.

Comment: catch will intercept "terminating errors" only. Try setting `$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"  ` on top of your script

Comment: I have added that code on top of the script. Only then my other exceptions are getting caught.

Comment: could you share your script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to non-terminating errors, you should be aware that PowerShell try/catch does not "catch" the fact that an executable returned an error exit code.  You can make it generate an exception like so:

```
some.exe someargs
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) { throw "some.exe failed with exit code $LastExitCode" }
```